# Decrease vertical space between cventries

Tags: spacing, cv, awesome-cv

This must be easy for you, but I am quite unable to get it right. Here is my code:

```
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
 \cventry
  {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering} % Degree
  {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)} % Institution
  {Pohang, S.Korea} % Location
  {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT} % Date(s)
  {}
 \cventry
  {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering} % Degree
  {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)} % Institution
  {Pohang, S.Korea} % Location
  {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT} % Date(s)
  {}
\end{cventries}
```

I want to decrease vertical space between two `\cventry` items. Here is my current output.

[image]

The used class for this resume is `awesome-cv.cls`.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using... [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)? If so, why style, as `\cventry`'s layout depends on this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2):

You can either patch the `\cventry` macro to reduce the space inserted after it using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\cventry}% <cmd>
  {\\ \end{tabular*}}% <search>
  {\\[-.5\normalbaselineskip]\end{tabular*}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

The above can be inserted just before `\begin{document}` and will provide a global change to the `\cventry` macro.

Alternatively, on a case-by-case basis, you can insert something like

```
\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
```

between `\cventry`s.

[image]

---

[References](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV#quick-start):

- [Edit Résumé on OverLeaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/tvmzpvdjfqxp)
- [Edit Résumé on ShareLaTeX.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)
- [Edit Cover Letter on OverLeaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv-cover-letter/pfzzjspkthbk)
- [Edit Cover Letter on ShareLaTeX.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/awesome-cv-cover-letter)